# About 2-adic representation of integers

Tags: number-theory, binary, p-adic-number-theory

How would I express -3 in 2-adic representation? Is it just revercimal calculation of binary expression of -3?

like: -3 = -11 in binary, so using revercimal, -11. in binary = 01. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the definition of those numbers.

For example, $-3$ is the number such that $(-3)+3=0$. Since $0=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 0\cdot2^n$ and $3=1\cdot2^0+1\cdot2^1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty 0\cdot2^n$, you have $-3=1\cdot2^0+0\cdot2^1+\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1\cdot2^n$.

I leave you the details.

Answer (score 1):

If $n \in \Bbb{Z}_p$, then we have

$$-n = \lim_{k\to\infty} (p^k - n) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \big( (p^k-1) - (n-1) \big).  $$

If we write $n-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k p^k$ with $a_k \in \{0, \cdots, p-1\}$, then this observation allows us to compute the $p$-adic representation of $-n$ as the (diminished) radix complement of $n-1$:

$$-n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(p-1-a_k)p^k. $$

**Example 1.** If $n = 3$, then $n-1 = 2 = \cdots00010_{(2)}$ and hence $-3 = \cdots11101_{(2)}$.

**Example 2.** In $\Bbb{Z}_7$, one of the square root $n$ of $2$ has the following expansion

$$n = \cdots6421216213_{(7)}.$$

Then $n-1 = \cdots6421216212_{(7)}$ and hence the other square root $-n$ can be expanded as

$$ -n = \cdots0245450454_{(7)}. $$

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot.

Comment: Can you explain to me the step where you state that all p-adics must have $-n=\lim _{k\rightarrow \infty }({p}^{k}-n)$

Comment: This clearly is not a conventional definition of a limit, otherwise it would be complete nonsense if taken to be the standard definition.

Comment: @Adam, The standard topology on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is given by the $p$-adic metric. You can check that $p^k$ converges to $0$ under this topology.

Comment: so as $k$ is made infinitely large, a prime power $p^k$ converges to 0?

Comment: Show me precisely what you mean by under this topology please.

Comment: @Adam, Under the $p$-adic norm $|\cdot|_p$, we have $|p^k - 0|_p = p^{-k} \to 0$ as $k\to\infty$. So $p^k$ converges to $0$ under this norm (or under the topology induced by $|\cdot|_p$).

Comment: ok well now you have just stated that $p^{-k} \rightarrow 0$ can you please elaborate on the justication for stating that this also implies that $p^{k} \rightarrow 0$ because again this is a highly unconventional definition of what it means  for a number to be greater than or less than zero as is indicated by the standard sign convention of +/ -

Comment: @Adam, The theory of $p$-adic number is a very well-developed area of mathematics, so I do not consider it unconventional. Moreover, since OP used the tag (p-adic number theory), I freely assumed that OP was already exposed with the basics of this theory and used it without explanation. On the other hand, perhaps I was not clear enough when using two different modes of convergences involved in my last comment. The point is, since $|p^k-0|_p=p^{-k}$ converges to $0$ under the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}$, $p^k$ converges to $0$ under the $p$-adic norm.

Comment: ok so does $\vert p^{k} - 0 \vert_p = \vert p^{k} \vert_p$ ? I am just not clear why the 0 is retained if this is the case, otherwise I need a better explanation as to why the additive identity needs to be kept in the expression

Comment: ok so you do not consider this to be unconventional? 
$p^{-k} \rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow p^{k} \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Adam, No. This is a completely standard business in $p$-adic number theory. And I think I clarified the point that $$\text{[$p^{-k}\to0$ under the Euclidean norm]}\quad\Rightarrow\quad\text{[$p^k\to0$ under the $p$-adic norm]}.$$ As for the expression $|p^k-0|_p$, I simply wanted to emphasize the definition of convergence in conjunction with the induced metric $(x,y)\mapsto|x-y|_p$.

Comment: Ok thankyou for you time.